# Is it possible to set a Hibernate Query Hint by default in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, query-hints

I must use the Hibernate Query Hint `HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH` in every requests that uses `DISTINCT` keyword in my Spring Boot application.
Instead of setting the hint with the `@QueryHint` annotation or the `Query.setHint` method, I'm wondering if there's a way to set it once for all queries, for example with an application property?